# What do `()` `{}` mean in a member initializer list? What's wrong with my code that the output is not what I expect?

Tags: c++

In my opinion, `p{n}` stands for `this.p=n` and `n(a)` means `this.n=this.a`, is this right?

I already define a constructor like `task1(int a,int n):a{a},n(n)...`. Why am I gettnig the output `a=1,n=2` when I input `1,2` and suppose `this.a=1,this.n=2`?

```
class task1 {
public:
    int a;
    int n;
    int p, q;
    task1(int a, int n) :a(a), n(a), p{ n }, q(n){
        cout << a << " " << n << " " << p << " " << q << endl;
    }
    

};
void main() {
    task1 t1 = task1(1, 2);

}
```

I input `1 2` and suppose it outputs `1 1 2 1` but actually it outputs `1 2 2 2`, why?

Comment: where did you get that from? in the initializer list the initializer refers to the parameter in case of ambiguity

Comment: Both `{}` initialization and `()` initialization are equivalent in initializer list. If you used different names for class members and constructor arguments, it would be easier to understand probably.

Comment: your parameters "n" and "a" hide the member variables "n" and "a", therefore you're always referencing to the parameters in your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Thats not right.

In the initializer list shadowing is a bit special. When you write

```
 struct foo {
     int n;
     foo(int n) : n(n) {}
 };
```

then it means the obvious: initialize the member `n` with value of parameter `n`. However inside the constructor, the parameter `n` does shadow the member of same name:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;


class task1 {
public:
    int a;
    int n;
    int p, q;
    task1(int a, int n) :a(a), n(a), p{ n }, q(n){
        cout << a << " " << n << " " << p << " " << q << endl;
        cout << this->a << " " << this->n << " " << p << " " << q << endl;
    }
    

};
int main() {
    task1 t1 = task1(1, 2);

}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/5cW4KxMza):

```
1 2 2 2
1 1 2 2
```

Both `p` and `q` are initialized with `2`. Though inside the constructor `n` refers to the parameter not the member (that would be `this->n`).